# Trying to copy row from sheet to another (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to accomplish here is a VBAmacro to copy four rows above the selected row below.

Here is my code :

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s2 As Worksheet, s3 As Worksheet
    Set s2 = ActiveSheet
    Set s3 = Sheets("New Sheet")
    Dim K As Long, N As Long, i As Long
    K = 1
    N = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        With Cells(i, "C")
            If .Value = "Scheduled Break" Then
                .EntireRow.Copy s3.Cells(K, 1)            
                K = K + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select    
End Sub
```

The copied row is "Scheduled Break". All I need to do is copy the four rows above that target row and the "scheduled break" one.

Comment: What if `scheduled break` is found on row 2? You can't copy 4 rows above from that? Edit: but to answer, use range like so: `range(cells(i-4,3),cells(i,3)).copy`

Comment: try changing `.EntireRow.Copy s3.Cells(K, 1)` to `.Range(Rows(i - 4), Rows(i)).Copy s3.Cells(K, 1)`

Comment: You will also need to increment K by 5 instead of 1. `K= K +5`

Comment: i've tried to use Scott's code but it is giving me an error "object undefined something...", even after changing the increment to 5 :( .. thanks though

Comment: Change to `s2.Range(Rows(i - 4), Rows(i)).Copy s3.Cells(K, 1)`

Comment: WORKING! :D that exactly what i need... Many thanks buddy :) .. rated as answer

Answer (score 0):

Change to s2.Range(Rows(i - 4), Rows(i)).Copy s3.Cells(K, 1)

Answered by Scott Craner and I quote it